# Difference between httpd and tomcat

Tags: linux, tomcat, httpd

What is the generic difference between the two processes on a linux box ?

I always thought they are the same thing, basically a web server so the users have some ui where they can make requests.

Answer (score 2):

Both are web servers, but they provide nearly opposite features when it comes to hosting dynamic webapps:

- Apache httpd has modules for directly hosting e.g. PHP or Python webapps, and it supports proxying requests to standalone webapps, whether they speak HTTP, or FastCGI (PHP-FPM), or uwsgi (Python/Ruby/etc). However, it cannot host *Java* apps directly – it has to forward the requests to another webserver which can, such as Tomcat or Jetty.
- Apache Tomcat directly supports hosting web apps written in Java (servlets, etc.). However, it doesn't support any other CGI interfaces, i.e. you cannot make it serve FastCGI.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation.